# Java 8 - For Each and removeIf

Tags: java, lambda

I am trying to perform the operation using the `ForEach` in Java 8 by combining the `removeIf` method. But I am getting the Error.

I am not able to combine the `forEach` and `removeIf` in the following program:

```
public class ForEachIterator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ints.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(ints);
        // Getting the Error in next line
        ints.forEach(ints.removeIf(i -> i%2 ==0));
        System.out.println(ints);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to remove all even values and print what you removed?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's no need for the `forEach`, the Lambda expression will work on all elements of the set

```
ints.removeIf(i -> i%2==0)
```

[removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):
"*Removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given predicate*"

**Simply...**

For each element (`i`) in the set (`ints`), remove it if (`removeIf`) the predicate (`i%2==0`) is true for this element (`i`).  This will act on the original set and return true if any elements where removed.

Answer (score 0):

the method **removeif** itself gives elements one by one as its passing parameter that's why we don't need to use forEach loop here.

*over ints ->*

```
ints.forEach(ints.lambdaEx)
```

it is causing two n loops causing n^2 iteration which is not needed here.

Just use "`removeif( n -> n % 2 == 0)`"